# Conflicts in generated file

Tags: git

Let's say there's file which had conflict due to many people worked on it simultaneously, but it's that kind of file which code you don't want to touch (big mess generated by automated tool usually as a result of wysiwyg editor). How do you solve conflict in such case?

Comment: Carefully :-/ If it's generated from another source, solve the conflicts in that source and regenerate. Else if you can't solve them manually, it might be simplest to rewind to the last-known-good revision and then remake the changes in order.

Answer (score 2):

With patience and `git mergetool`.

---

Alternately you can choose a version to keep and discard the others.

```
git pull -s recursive -X theirs
```

will pull the content from the remote and solve merge conflicts by using the remote version.

Do this **only** if you can afford to discard your changes to the conflicted files.